# Using Simple Date Formatter to get year and month from String timestamp

Tags: java

```
String myDate = new String("2011-06-23T00:00:00");
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            this.thedate = format.parse(myDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing, but I have a timestamp that will be a string and I want to parse out the year and month. This is what I have so far.

Comment: BTW, it is an Android related question? It seems to be a core Java question. Fixed the tag from 'android' to 'java'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" as a pattern for the `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess format should be this:

```
format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```